# Why function expression is called when there are function declaration and function expression with same name?

Tags: javascript

Here I have two function declarations with same name.

```
function a() {
    console.log('a1')
}
function a() {
    console.log('a2')
}
a();
```

It make senses that `a()` prints **a2**.

And here are a function declarations and a function expression.

```
b = function() {
    console.log('b1')
}
function b() {
    console.log('b2')
}

b();
```

But here `b()` prints **b1**, what is the reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`function b()` will [hoist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) the definition to the top of the containing scope. As a result, it is declared first. Following that, `b` is then assigned to with your `b = function` assignment, and when you call `b()` it then logs 'b1'.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the cause of hoisting. because hoisting moves all declarations to the top of the current scope (to the top of the current script or the current function).
**and here the function assign to **b** for hoisting.**